# how to avoid passing same parameter through multiple methods

Tags: ruby

```
def foo(a)
  # some computation
  bar(a, b)
end

def bar(a,b)
  # some computation
  baz(a, b, c)
end

def baz(a, b ,c)
  print a
end
```

How to avoid passing same parameter (a) to all methods? One way is to make parameter `a` as an instance variable. What is the right way to do this?

Comment: A little bit of context would help someone trying to help you, because I don't see any harm in passing them to each function

Comment: In future debugging would be very difficult, if i want to make a small change.

Answer (score 0):

There is no single solution which works in every case, and often, passing the parameters explicitly is simply the best choice, especially when it comes to debugging.

You can use instance variables, but I would not introduce a new instance variable for the sole reason not to avoid passing it down the call chain. It should have its own value in addition.

One approach which I can see often in projects, is to us a single parameter hash, where the new parameters are added:

```
def foo(a)
  ....
  bar({a:a, b:b})
end

def bar(par)
  ....
  par[:c] = c
end

def baz(par)
   par[:a]+par[:b]+par[:c]
end
```

This is not without drawbacks either. If you, for instance, forget to "add" a necessary parameter, this will either yield wrong results or throw an exception (depending on how to used them), while forgetting them explicitly via the parameter list, would be found at compile time already.

I would make the decisiion depending on the length of the parameter lists involved. If the number of parameters to a methods is larger than 5, I would start thinking, whether a different design might be more appropriate.

Comment: Just use keyword parameters for that: `def baz(**par)` and call it like `baz(a: 42, b: :foo)`.

Comment: You are right. I didn't consider this alternative, since I'm working in a project with a Ruby version which doesn't support keyword parameters yet. Otherwise, it's of course a feasible alternative.

Answer (score -2):

Answering the question stated: yes, ruby is a stateful OO language, *having* mutable everything. So in ruby one might introduce *instance variables*:

```
class MyClass
  def foo(a)
    @a = a
    # some computation
    bar(b)
  end

  def bar(b)
    @b = b
    # some computation
    baz(c)
  end

  def baz(c)
    print [@a, @b, c].inspect
  end
end
```

In the real life, **the best practice would be to *avoid using instance variables wherever possible*, and pass everything across methods**. That might save you days of debugging in the future.